# ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint throwing HTTP 405 error after modifying Uri format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Angular frontend and a backend in ASP.NET Core Web API. The Angular app calls the Web API using `www.website.com/api/v1/FetchData` which works fine.

This Web API application is set up as a website in IIS with specific app pool.

NEW CHANGE:

I added more Web APIs under the main website. Each is a separate Web API project in solution file.

In IIS wwwroot folder there is a main folder "webapp", each webapi is under a subfolder under it called `webApi1`, `webApi2`, `webApi3`. Under the `Website` in IIS, we added each subsite (Web API library) as a "Web Application".

So new set of URI for each nested Web APIs looks like this:

```
www.website.com/webApi1/api/v1/FetchData

www.website.com/webApi2/api/v1/FetchData

www.website.com/webApi3/api/v1/FetchData
```

**Issue**

Now when I hit the Angular app, the call goes up to IIS of the server hosting `WebApi1`. But we get HTTP 405 error. When I checked logs it contains `"www.website.com/webApi1/api/v1/FetchData 405 0 1 1"`
where 405 is HTTP Error and 3rd 1 is `sc-win32-status` which means "Incorrect Function".

For each API controller, we defined the same routing attribute. No changes in that:

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]/[action]")]
```

What could be wrong? Please advice. I don't see any issues with code or the way IIS is set up. I also checked the HTTP Verbs and there is no issue. The `FetchData` endpoint is configured as POST call and we can see POST in the logs.

Comment: The error information doesn't show the key factor that lead to this 405 error, please enable failed request tracing, it will provide the key error and warning.

Comment: @samwu - can you please tell me how to enable that? I tried something I found on the internet but didnt work. If u have a link with good documentation, pls let me know

Comment: You will have to show the entire line (all fields) of that 405 IIS log entry. It is almost impossible to see "www.website.com/webApi1/api/v1/FetchData" under `cs-uri-stem`, and `sc-win32-status` are rarely useful.

Comment: @CodeTruthSeeker This link should help you: [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: I followed the steps written in this blog to recreate the routing logic and it worked. [Routing logic for subsites](https://medium.com/@suryasreepada/how-to-run-multiple-net-core-apis-under-one-iis-application-f14c70881498) Hence accepting this solution as my answer.